# Introduce new property member and new enum dynamically within custom aspect (PostSharp)

Tags: c#, enums, attributes, aop, postsharp

I have created a custom `AssemblyLevelAspect` in PostSharp which looks through all types in a namespace and changes some attributes (using `CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect`) depending on what it finds.

However, in some cases, I need to modify an enum as part of the aspect. To clarify, here's my code:

```
public class Foo
{
    [MyAttribute("enum1")]
    [SourceAttribute("MyReference")]
    public Bar Value { get; set; }

    [TargetAttribute("MyReference")]
    public MyEnum ValueName { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    enum1
}
```

My aspect will add new `MyAttribute` decorations to `Foo.Value`, but for each one, it must add a corresponding enumerator to `MyEnum`. Since (I think) this is impossible, I'm hoping it is possible instead to introduce a new member to supersede `ValueName`, say `ValueName2`, which is of a new enum type which I construct and emit dynamically. `ValueName2` would then be tied to `Value` by changing the parameter of `SourceAttribute` to "MyReference2" and adding `[TargetAttribute("MyReference2")]` to the new `ValueName2` property.

How can I introduce `ValueName2` dynamically within the aspect using [`IntroduceMemberAttribute`](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_introducememberattribute)? And is it possible to emit/introduce a new enum (the type of `ValueName2`) at this stage that will exist in my assembly?

Comment: I don't think that PostSharp is so mighty. PostSharp can't add a new dynamically named members and can't create a new type. What is the motivation for adding members to enum dynamically? If it would be possible then C# compiler would not see dynamically generated anyway, unless you reference directly the resulting assembly (like from nuget).

Comment: @JakubLinhart Basically, I'm generating C# classes from XSD using xsd.exe and I'm having to shoehorn attributes onto some properties afterwards (using PostSharp) due to Problem 1 described [here](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/problems-with-using-xsdexe-to-generate-net-classes-from-the-fpml-xsd-schema-introduction-to-using-fpml-with-net-tools-part-4/). As that blog alludes to, the problem is in multiple places, and requires an additional corresponding enumeration to be added for each attribute added (for certain classes). I could modify the generated code, but AOP is more elegant.

Comment: @Neo, I have the similar problem. `xsd.exe` seems to be [bad since 2003](https://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/XsdCodeGenTool). 
Other xsd.exe alternatives worth investigating are [xsd2code](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/), [codaxy/xsd2](https://github.com/codaxy/xsd2), [WSCF](https://github.com/WSCF/WSCF) or xsd.exe sources (they are available somewhere).